# Vuejs cache images from url, avoid re-fetching

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, browser-cache

I'm building a simple gallery + slideshow app.
In the gallery component I have all the urls and display them in a `GalleryItem` component.

```
<gallery-item v-for="i in images" :item="i" :key="i.uid"/>
```

`GalleryItem` then uses

```
<img :src="item.url"/>
```

to display the image.
If the user clicks on any `GalleryItem` it will be highlighted in a lightbox/slideshow component.

```
<lightbox :item="highlightedItem"/>
```

which again uses

```
<img :src="item.url"/>
```

I naively expected the browser to cache that request and not reload the exact same url, but that's exactly what's happening.

Is there any elegant way to avoid this and cache the image when loaded once?

Comment: Turns out the browser *does* cache, unless the dev-tools are open and `disable-cache` is active, so no issue in production.

Comment: I owe you... spent ages trying to work this out, but I too had 'disable cache' active, oops!

Comment: You can try loading all images once and then use v-show to conditionaly display them. This way you will avoid refetching.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement caching images with a service worker.

An example service worker library that you can use is [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies).
With Workbox you can define a URL you want to cache and multiple different caching strategies. Similar to the following code example just replace the RegExp with one that fits your use case, for example using the image extensions.

If your images don't change as in the same url always points to the same image, I would recommend you to use the cacheFirst strategy, as then you will not need to send a request to the server if the image is already in the cache.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/styles/'),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst()
);
```

Comment: how do i ship this to end user? Should I need to ask to install this plugin for caching to work?